# Exception caught on transport layer while starting elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one elastic search instance that is running as a windows service. While starting my one more new instance getting the following error. I have given the different cluster name and port in `.yml` file.

```
[2018-02-09T12:47:52,117][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] initialized
[2018-02-09T12:47:52,132][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] starting ...
[2018-02-09T12:47:52,601][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [node-one] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9301}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9301}, {[::1]:9301}
[2018-02-09T12:47:52,929][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [node-one] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x7d25302a, L:/127.0.0.1:49514 - R:/127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 253 hex: fd
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:352) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1377) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
[2018-02-09T12:47:52,929][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [node-one] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xda7bbb7d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49513 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 253 hex: fd
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:352) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1377) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
[2018-02-09T12:47:53,757][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [node-one] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x6bef02cd, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49517 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 253 hex: fd
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:352) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1377) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
[2018-02-09T12:47:53,836][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [node-one] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xf3c355df, L:/127.0.0.1:49519 - R:/127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 253 hex: fd
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:352) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1377) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
[2018-02-09T12:47:54,758][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [node-one] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x1a807a39, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49525 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 253 hex: fd
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:352) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1377) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
[2018-02-09T12:47:54,883][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [node-one] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x8b7a93c5, L:/127.0.0.1:49528 - R:/127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 253 hex: fd
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:352) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1377) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
[2018-02-09T12:47:55,774][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [node-one] new_master {node-one}{CqKbO0RGTO-1KvSXz0mdYQ}{LRLXEJ13SvuhYp3HrSHAFg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2018-02-09T12:47:55,883][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [node-one] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2018-02-09T12:47:56,087][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [node-one] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9210}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9210}, {[::1]:9210}
[2018-02-09T12:47:56,087][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] started
[2018-02-09T12:53:16,782][INFO ][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] running graceful exit on windows
[2018-02-09T12:53:16,782][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] stopping ...
[2018-02-09T12:53:16,798][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] stopped
[2018-02-09T12:53:16,814][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] closing ...
[2018-02-09T12:53:16,826][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one] closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I too ran in to the same problem, and managed to resolve it by doing the following

1. Ensure the cluster.name and node.name are set correctly.
2. If you are running a single node, make sure network.host is correctly set to a reachable IP, and all nodes are in the same subnet.
3. If you are in a cluster, make sure the master node's published address resolves on each data node's DNS. i.e. from each data node, if you ping the master node host name, it should resolve to the published address (network.publish_host) of the master node. (In my case this was the problem. Since I had just upgraded from an older version, somehow, it wasn't connecting to the master correctly and throwing this error. After double checking the host names and setting the publish_host to a particular IP reachable by all data nodes, the problem went away.)